# Html form, how to send data by traditional post and jquery ajax to various servers at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to save html form data in my server and to an another server. For this data is sending by traditional post (refreshing the page) to local server and also by jquery ajax post (or javascript) to the remote server. The html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='e.js'></script>
<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" id="registration" action="receiver1.php">  
  Name: <input type="text" id="nameq" name="name" value="">
  <span class="error">* </span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
  <span class="error">* </span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" id="website" name="website" value="">
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="other">Other  
  <span class="error">* </span>
  <br><br>
        <table width='100%'>
            <tr>
                <td align='center'>
        <input type='image' src='image/submit_button.jpg'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
</html>
```

here action="receiver1.php" is file in my server http://localhost/receiver1.php. I make handler on input type='image', e.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table tr input:image").click(function() {
        var cln = $("#nameq").val();
        $.post("https://remote-server/receiver2.php", {"cln": cln});
    });
});
```

https://remote-server/receiver2.php is file in an another server. But it does not work, I can't receive data in remote server. Have someone a perfect solution for this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain security probably stopping you doing this. You could post to one host and have that host use Curl to update the second host.

Comment: no in php I have header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); I do not want post to one host,  use curl etc. It is important to solve this problem as is